# JavascriptInterface cannot be called in H5

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, vue.js

I used `vue` to write an h5 page embedded in the app. The page and app use `window.JSInterface` to communicate. I need to call `JSInterface(javascriptinterface)` to access the `getResString` method in Android to get user information, but now `JSinterface` is not called or the call fails. As a result, I cannot access any method that Android mounts to `JSInterface`.

The Android programmer told me that H5 didn't call any methods, and I didn't have his code here. He told me exactly that there would be no problem with the code on the Android side. It must be my problem.

More importantly, because the problem was `JSInterface`, I couldn't debug it and couldn't start.

Below is the code that I call the JSInterface part, please see how I should do it. thank you all.

```
if (window.JSInterface) {
      this.test.push(1);     //test:[1]
      this.token = window.JSInterface.getResString("TOKEN");
      this.test.push(2);    //test:[1]
      this.appid = window.JSInterface.getResString("APP_ID");
      this.info_id.userid = window.JSInterface.getResString("USER_ID");
      this.info_id.device_id = window.JSInterface.getResString("DEVICE_ID");
      this.$i18n.locale = window.JSInterface.getResString("SYSTEM_LA");
    }
    this.test.push(3)     // test:[1]


goNativePage(val) {
          if (window.JSInterface) {
            //also can not be called 
            window.JSInterface.toNativePage(val, "");
          }
```

console report a error : Type error : window.JSInterface.getResString is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Andriod guy's fault,
He confused the dependent libraries